# MongoDB suddenly stop responding because of background processes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Our mongo DB suddenly stops responding to any request and throws error messages like:

```
 MongoError: cannot perform operation: a background operation is currently running for collection demo2.users
     at MessageStream.messageHandler (....../node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
     at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
     at processIncomingData (...../node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
     at MessageStream._write (....../node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
     at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
     at Socket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:719:22)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
     at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
     at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
     at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
   ok: 0,
   code: 12587,
   codeName: 'BackgroundOperationInProgressForNamespace'
}
```

This error comes out from a connection to mongo:

The operation issued by my application is just a connection to the database:

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      ...confOptions,
    })
      .then(async client => {
        return client;
      })
      .catch(err => {

        // And here is where the error comes
        console.log(err);
        return null;
      })
```

We are using MongoDB driver with node.js. MongoDB and node.js are on the same server (Ubuntu Linux 20.04.2)

For reusing the mongo connections we use the npm generic-pool library, and **only when we start the server** we setup at the beginning all the indexes and the collections with the commands:

```
  const existingCollection = await mongo.db(databaseName).listCollections({ name }).next();
  if (existingCollection) {
    await mongo.db(databaseName).command({
      collMod: name,
      validator: { $jsonSchema: schema },
      validationLevel: 'strict',
      validationAction: 'error',
    });
  } else {
    await mongo.db(databaseName).createCollection(name, {
      validator: { $jsonSchema: schema },
      validationLevel: 'strict',
      validationAction: 'error',
    });
  }
```

and ensuring indexes with

```
  await mongo.db(databaseName).collection(collectionName).createIndex({
    clientNumber: 1,
  }, { unique: true });
```

But it looks like mongo starts suddenly to make indexing, validations, and other background operations that lock everything - this happens mostly after few days of a running the server.

The only way mongo starts again to respond is to restart it.

Has anyone any idea what could be the cause of this? Or is there any way to stop any locking background operations of mongo?

Comment: If the server truly responded with that error to every request, you would have a different error given to you by the driver.

Comment: @D.SM This is the error provided by the driver. And in the mongo logs I see all the active operations like listCollections, indexing, validating etc.

Comment: This is an error that the server produced in response to *some operations* which you haven't specified.

Comment: @D.SM this error comes on *each* request. It comes when in a request there is a try to use connection from the generic-pool, the returned mongo client comes with significant timeout and is undefined. After restarting my node server, it is still not possible to build again connection to the mongodb. Only after restarting mongo everything starts to work normally again. Connecting to mongo with nosqlbooster is also not possible when this happens...

Comment: By "request" I assume you mean some a web request of some kind. This is immaterial to the interaction between your application and the database. What matters is operations issued by your application to the database.

Comment: @D.SM The operation issued by my application is just a connection to the database - I just fixed my comment and added it

Comment: OK, I retracted the downvote but to make progress on this you still need to figure out what operation is actually failing since the stack trace isn't saying anything about that.

Comment: And server version is missing from the question.